# Want to get minutes between two ISO 8601 times in two different time zones with joda

Tags: java, android, jodatime, iso8601

I have two strings from an android application in ISO 8601 format that I am trying to find the amount of minutes in between the two times. I was pointed to Joda Time which has been immensely helpful. However I have discovered now that one String is in UTC time and the other is my local time.

For example 
"2012-05-11T02:34:18+00:00" is UTC and
"2012-05-10T21:44:09-05:00" is my local time

I have the following block of code which finds the number of minutes between the two times. My question is how can I go about to change the UTC time to my local time in order to get an accurate minutes in between

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(currentTime);
DateTime end = new DateTime(laterTime);
int min = Minutes.minutesBetween(start,end).getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I go about to change the UTC time to my local time in order to get an accurate minutes in between?

My understanding is that you don't need to.

A DateTime instance represents a point on the time line, together with a timezone which controls how the time-point is mapped to a time frame (e.g. when you call the getters).  When you take a time difference between a pair of `DateTime` instance, you get a measure representing the duration between two points on the timeline.  This is independent of the timezones.

In other words, assuming that the two `DateTime` instances were created properly, your code should work as-is.